# react-chartjs-2 change axes text color

Tags: reactjs, charts, styling

I did a lot of searching but nothing I tried works to change the axes text color. However, I am able to change the grid color to white in `scales.yAxes.grid.color`. This is what I have right now:

```
  render(){
        return (
            <div className = "chart">
                <Line
                    data = {this.state.chartData}

                    options= {{
                        maintainAspectRatio: false,
                        scales: {
                            yAxes:{
                                grid: {
                                    drawBorder: true,
                                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                                },
                                ticks:{
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                    fontColor: 'white'
                                }
                            },
                            xAxes: {
                                grid: {
                                    drawBorder: true,
                                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                                },
                                ticks:{
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                    fontColor: 'white'
                                }
                            },
                        }
                    }}
                    width = {20}
                    height = {200}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a code sandbox? How do you set up the rest of your chart config? Does setting any of these other produce expected effects? I would guess there is some configuration default that is over riding this setup.

Comment: Here's a code sandbox with the same issue (I am trying to change the axes' text color to red): https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-brook-75nwb?file=/src/Chart.js

Comment: backgroundColor and borderColor work as expected to change the line and node colors (not too sure what 'color' changes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

font color can be set by "color" instead of "fontColor"

```html
render(){
        return (
            <div className = "chart">
                <Line
                    data = {this.state.chartData}

                    options= {{
                        maintainAspectRatio: false,
                        scales: {
                            yAxes:{
                                grid: {
                                    drawBorder: true,
                                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                                },
                                ticks:{
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                    color: 'white',
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                }
                            },
                            xAxes: {
                                grid: {
                                    drawBorder: true,
                                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                                },
                                ticks:{
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                    color: 'white',
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                }
                            },
                        }
                    }}
                    width = {20}
                    height = {200}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```